# How can I connect Android Emulator to the Internet?

Tags: android-emulator

I am new to the android development . I have tried to connect internet with Android emulator, but i am not able to connect. I have tried following command in cmp.

> emulator -avd my_id  -http-proxy
>   http://xxx.xxx.x.x:8080
>
> emulator -avd my_id -dns-server
>   xxx.xxx.xxx.xx -http-proxy
>   http://xxx.xxx.x.x:8080

And also I have set proxy settings in the emulator (settings -> Wireless & Networks ->Mobile Networks -> Access Point Names). Also , I set proxy settings in eclipse (Windows-> Preferences-> Android-> Launch-> Default Emulator Options).still i am able to get the internet access to the emulator.  Please any one give the suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the top of the emulator there should be a 3G icon then an icon next too it displaying what would be network strength bars on a normal phone.  If some of those bars are not lit up then your emulator may have lost its connection.  This happens every once in a while.  Try restarting the emulator.  If you have already done this try deleting and creating a new emulator.  If your computer has an internet connection you shouldn't have to do anything extra to get the connection on the emulator working.

Answer (score 0):

you can do some extra setting if you are using some proxy server go to setting -> wireless and network -> mobile networks -> acess point name -> click on name -> change there proxy ="http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx", port="8080" and authentication type = none 
 then click on menu button and click on save and restart the emulator . its done.